# SQLiteAssetHelper upgrade exception

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, syntax

I have an app using SQLiteAssetHelper. I'm trying to update its database to include an additional table.

All is well except I cannot make the primary key to autoincrement. Whatever I try gives me an exception.

I reckon it could be a syntax issue since using INTEGER instead of INT also crashes the app.

Where can I find a reference for the syntax that SQLiteAssetHelper uses?

Thank you all.

The offending script looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE heat (
_id int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
amount int,
comment text
);
```

Even when I get the script to work (is it `AUTOINCREMENT` or `auto_increment`?), insert statements fail to add a value in the `_id` column. It is left blank.

```
final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

cv.put( KEY_AMOUNT, lAmount );
cv.put( KEY_COMMENT, sComment );

final long lId = m_db.insert( TABLE_NAME, null, cv );
```

Comment: can you paste your table creation statement ?

Comment: put your code for inserting new record

Answer (score 0):

Change the database version to upgrade the table

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: No, no. The problem is not there. I can update fine. What I cannot do is to add a new table with an autoincrement on the primary key. Without the autoincrement, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

`AUTOINCREMENT` requires an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, an `INT PRIMARY KEY` won't do. Changing that fixed the problem with the SQL you posted. If you have other problems, please post the exception message and code that causes it.

Comment: The problem is that the script that SQLiteAssetHelper requires for upgrading fails to work with INTEGER.